# Embedded Jetty 8 hot deploy classes (using Maven)

Tags: java, maven, jetty, embed

I have a standard Maven webapp structure defined, and it uses Spring MVC.

I am using an embedded Jetty server (java class)  for testing the application in development.

The code used to create the Jetty server is outlined below. If I make changes to any JSP files, the changes are **immediately** visible in the browser.

However if I change any class files, e.g Controllers, the changes are not hot deployed?

What do I have to do get this to work?

I have searched this and I think I need to use the class **org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner** and specifically the **setScanInterval** method, but not sure how to wire this up?

Here is the code to create the Server

```
    String webAppDir = "src/main/webapp/";
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext webApp = new WebAppContext();
    webApp.setContextPath("/");
    webApp.setDescriptor(webAppDir + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    webApp.setResourceBase(webAppDir);
    webApp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    HandlerCollection hc = new HandlerCollection();
    ContextHandlerCollection contextHandlerCollection = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    hc.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contextHandlerCollection });
    hc.addHandler(webApp);
    server.setHandler(hc);
    return server;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hot deployment you need to use the WebAppProvider and the DeploymentManager.  Those you can configure to manage the scanning for changes and the reloading of the webapp.  So it is clear, the WebappContext is not what manages the deployment of a webapp, it is merely the container class that is gets deployed so there is another mechanism that works outside of that which can handle the concepts of deploy/redeploy.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-deploy/src/test/resources/jetty-deploy-wars.xml

You can take that chunk of xml there and convert into the java calls you need to do this embedded.

Or use something like the jrebel jvm plugin which provides for automatic class reloading.

Comment: I followed the examples above but in the end did not decide to use hot deploying of classes as my app was using Spring and thus was slow to restart every time I made an edit!

Comment: I have heard good things about jrebel addressing that issue, I think they have free trials if you want to give it a whirl