# Wicket app with jetty embedded server

Tags: web-applications, jetty, wicket, embedded-jetty, rundeck

How I can enable a jetty embedded server in my wicket application that could to allow me  to control my application in a deamon way like above:

```
java -jar wicket_jetty_webapp.jar start
java -jar wicket_jetty_webapp.jar stop
java -jar wicket_jetty_webapp.jar status
```

Rundeck application, that uses Grails framework, works in this way. The google refine use the same approach. For me it's awesome to use a web app with the same way.

Someone know a good resources or articles that explain this subject, with maven?

Also, it's possible to configure jetty to offer a live update feature like play framework offers or like using JRebel?

Comment: seems like a similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737542/embedded-jetty-8-hot-deploy-classes-using-maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use maven you can help some like:

POM:

> ```
>   <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
>       <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
>       <version>${jetty.version}</version>             <scope>provided</scope>
>   </dependency>   </dependencies>     <build>         <resources>             <resource>
>           <filtering>false</filtering>
>           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>           </resource>             <resource>
>           <filtering>false</filtering>
>           <directory>src/main/java</directory>
>           <includes>
>               <include>**</include>
>           </includes>
>           <excludes>
>               <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
>           </excludes>             </resource>         </resources>        <testResources>             <testResource>
>           <filtering>false</filtering>
>           <directory>src/test/resources</directory>           </testResource>             <testResource>
>           <filtering>false</filtering>
>           <directory>src/test/java</directory>
>           <includes>
>               <include>**</include>
>           </includes>
>           <excludes>
>               <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
>           </excludes>             </testResource>         </testResources>        <plugins>           <plugin>
>           <inherited>true</inherited>
>           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>2.5.1</version>
>           <configuration>
>               <source>1.6</source>
>               <target>1.6</target>
>               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
>               <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
>               <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
>           </configuration>            </plugin>           <plugin>
>           <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>${jetty.version}</version>
>           <configuration>
>               <connectors>
>                   <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
>                       <port>8080</port>
>                       <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
>                   </connector>
>                   <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
>                       <port>8443</port>
>                       <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
>                       <keystore>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/keystore</keystore>
>                       <password>wicket</password>
>                       <keyPassword>wicket</keyPassword>
>                   </connector>
>               </connectors>
>           </configuration>            </plugin>           <plugin>
>           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>           <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>2.9</version>
>           <configuration>
>               <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
>           </configuration>            </plugin>       </plugins>
> ```

Main.class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int timeout = (int) Duration.ONE_HOUR.getMilliseconds();

        Server server = new Server();
        SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();

        // Set some timeout options to make debugging easier.
        connector.setMaxIdleTime(timeout);
        connector.setSoLingerTime(-1);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        Resource keystore = Resource.newClassPathResource("/keystore");
        if (keystore != null && keystore.exists()) {
            // if a keystore for a SSL certificate is available, start a SSL
            // connector on port 8443.
            // By default, the quickstart comes with a Apache Wicket Quickstart
            // Certificate that expires about half way september 2021. Do not
            // use this certificate anywhere important as the passwords are
            // available in the source.

            connector.setConfidentialPort(8443);

            SslContextFactory factory = new SslContextFactory();
            factory.setKeyStoreResource(keystore);
            factory.setKeyStorePassword("wicket");
            factory.setTrustStoreResource(keystore);
            factory.setKeyManagerPassword("wicket");
            SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector(factory);
            sslConnector.setMaxIdleTime(timeout);
            sslConnector.setPort(8443);
            sslConnector.setAcceptors(4);
            server.addConnector(sslConnector);

            System.out.println("SSL access to the quickstart has been enabled on port 8443");
            System.out.println("You can access the application using SSL on https://localhost:8443");
            System.out.println();
        }

        WebAppContext bb = new WebAppContext();
        bb.setServer(server);
        bb.setContextPath("/");
        bb.setWar("src/main/webapp");

        // START JMX SERVER
        // MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        // MBeanContainer mBeanContainer = new MBeanContainer(mBeanServer);
        // server.getContainer().addEventListener(mBeanContainer);
        // mBeanContainer.start();

        server.setHandler(bb);

        try {
            System.out.println(">>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP");
            server.start();
            System.in.read();
            System.out.println(">>> STOPPING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER");
            server.stop();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I'm help that =)